# Access REST API on Windows Azure Virtual Machine via IP

Tags: windows, azure, rest, api, cross-domain

I currently have a SQL Database and REST API residing on an in house development server. When on the premises my Mac uses a Reverse Proxy (in Apache) to connect and use the REST API on the in house development server. This is to avoid CORS issues. The reverse proxy looks like the following:

```
ProxyPass /api/ http://192.168.1.250:80/
```

I wish to move the in house SQL Database and REST API to a Windows Azure Virtual Machine.

Is it possible to do this/is this a viable solution to accessing the REST API remotely? When publishing a website in IIS on a Windows Azure VM access is allowed via a cloudapp.net domain. Is it possible to access the site via an IP address?

I have looked into setting up a VM with a static IP but I am unsure if this would actually solve the above problem - so before spending any more time on this it would be great if someone better versed in this area could chime in!

Any help and guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Rich

Comment: Have you considered VPN (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-network/)?

Comment: According to the Azure doc's I would need to implement a cross premises virtual network:

"Cross-Premises and Hybrid solutions can be somewhat more complex to plan than a Cloud-Only virtual network configuration. Often, these types of connections require collaboration with your network engineer because they involve coordinating network routing as well as configuring VPN devices."

Which I would like to avoid, is the VM idea not a viable solution?

Comment: So I'm the last person to claim any expertise re: networking, so I don't know if a static ip solves your CORS problem. It's certainly possible to reserve an IP for a VM and access the VM directly via the IP though.